# show input date calender onclick

Tags: html, jquery

I am using the datepicker with the html input date:

```
<input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday">
```

If I click on the calendar icon, it will open the datepicker.
But how can I realize an onclick option for the input field to open the datepicker?

```
$( "#birthday" ).click(function() {
  // open picker
});
```

Comment: Can you try with `<input type="date" onclick="this.showPicker()">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onfocus event to open calendar, like this:

```
  <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday" onfocus="this.showPicker()">
```

You can read more about this function in [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/showPicker)

Comment: than I get: this.showPicker() ist not a function